# QtTimer сбивается

Tags: qt5

Приветствую всех знатоков Qt!
Решил написать простенький метрономчик,и столкнулся с такой проблемой:метроном ошибается в темпе чаще меня)
Реализация такая:у главного окна есть переменная типа QTimer,запускаем его как start(1000/bpm),где bpm-удары в минуту.Соединяем сигнал timeout со слотом этого же окна,который воспроизводит wav-файл.Если послушать метроном,то время от времени (раз в 10-20 секунд) наблюдаются резкие скачки,то есть интервал между двумя ударами маленький,потом снова все нормально.

Comment: сбивается скорее всего не таймер, а слот, выполняющий проигрывание звука. запустите таймер без звука и в слоте проверяйте, сколько времени прошло от прошлого вызова (через `time.elapsed`).

Comment: немного информации по теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421675/qtimer-not-accurate-at-all

Comment: Спасибо,прикрутил QTime, последил.Больше похоже на косяк воспроизведения - с интервалом до вызова слота все нормально, незначительный разброс вне зависимости от timertype.Еще одну странность нашел - в самом начале несколько ударов в два раза реже нужного делает,хотя слот работает как надо.При том перестал ловить сбития с темпа в виде одноразовых падений интервала,магия какая-то.

Answer (score 0):

проблема решается добавлением еще одного таймера,который будет следить за временем от начала клика и останавливать воспроизведение звука заранее(до следующего вызова функции,озвучивающей клик.Если интервал основного таймера 1000*60/bpm , то у этого 1000*60/(bpm+30) ).Дело то ли в том,что wav файл длиннее тех интервалов,что используются в метрономе,то ли в долгом вызове функции play() в случае,если сейчас уже что-то проигрывается.
На винде таким образом удалось поднять вдвое-втрое темп без ошибок,но на андроиде все равно жутко сбивается(